# Bokeh server doesn't work in Windows but works in Linux

Tags: bokeh

I have the same code, when I run it from Linux it works, when I run it from Windows it doesn't work without giving any error. The browser launches and keeps hanging, no output. Tried many browsers in Windows (Chrome, Internet Explorer, Opera, and Mozilla Firefox), same problem.
These two different computer, Windows in one, Linux in the other.
Tried both:
bokeh serve filename.py
and
bokeh serve filename.py --show
Same problem regardless of the command.

Any idea what is wrong with the Windows side of things?

Actually it's for all files I run with Bokeh server in Windows, it's not just one .py file, all of them do not work.[image: Windows command]

[image: Windows command without --show]

Comment: There's an known incompatibility with Bokeh and Tornado v4.5. You should check your tornado version and pin to v4.4.2 if that's the case.

Comment: checked it. It is version 4.5.1.0 using tornado.version_info. How do I install v4.4.2? and how do I pin to it?

Comment: Either ``pip install tornado=4.4.2`` or ``conda install tornado=4.4.2`` will downgrade tornado to the desired version. If you have a requirements.txt or environment.yml file, you could include the tornado version in there.

Comment: Installed tornado 4.4.2, It works now. Thanks.